# Teradata Connector for Hadoop failing with out of bounds exception

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, teradata

I'm trying to push from a Hadoop cluster to Teradata using Teradata Connector (TDCH). The entire process involves copying the previous day's data (based on partition) from a hive table to a hive external table, stored in HDFS as a csv, which is then pushed to Teradata. The partition is not sent to Teradata, only used to determine what to push. All of this is triggered from a shell script.

It successfully writes to csv but fails on the Teradata push with java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 44. Both tables have 44 columns, so there should be no index of 44. In the console, processor.TeradataBatchInsertProcessor prints out sql for 'create output stage table' which includes an additional column "TDCH_BI_TASKID" VARCHAR(40) NOT CASESPECIFIC NULL) NO PRIMARY INDEX.

I might have though that I had an issue with my columns matching up between tables, but the strange thing is that the push works fine when pushing only a small number of rows (eg 3 instead of the 1.5 million or so for an entire day), and the additional column "TDCH_BI_TASKID" is created in the stage table here as well, so that doesn't seem to be the cause of the out of bounds exception.

The error:

```
  Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 44
        at com.teradata.connector.hdfs.serde.HdfsTextSerDe.deserialize(HdfsTextSerDe.java:298)
        at com.teradata.connector.common.ConnectorCombineInputFormat$ConnectorCombineFileRecordReader.getCurrentValue(ConnectorCombineInputFormat.java:402)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.getCurrentValue(MapTask.java:535)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.getCurrentValue(MapContextImpl.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.getCurrentValue(WrappedMapper.java:86)
        at com.teradata.connector.common.ConnectorMMapper.run(ConnectorMMapper.java:122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
```

Comment: Look at your raw data. There are probably rows with extra separators.

Comment: I have, but there don't seem to be any extra. Each row will always contain empty fields, so the csv has a lot of row,row,,,,,,,,,row etc but they still match up

Comment: I've only looked at a few manually, but now I'm trying to formulate a regex to grep for extra "columns"

Comment: Check for missing row delimiters as well, hive will just happily ignore that kind of stuff.

Comment: You're right, I have found an extra delimiter, just in a sample of the csv on which I was testing my regex. Thank you, is there any suggestion you have for how to prevent this?

Comment: Well, it kinds of depends.  Are the extra delimiters in the data?  If so, are the fields quoted?  Can you change the delimiter? Stuff like that.